# does function WorksheetFunction.CountIf work in vba (outlook)?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, countif

I'm trying to compare value using both outlook email body and excel range values, but when it comes to compare them, the function WorksheetFunction.CountIf does not work at all.

even if I paste something using vba in outlook to excel worksheet the type seems differently than the used in excel. (I compared paste values with characters typed directly in excel and it doens't match).

any suggestion?

peace of the code, right below:

```
With New MSForms.DataObject
.PutInClipboard
strText = objSel.Application.Selection.text

End With


Dim i1 As Long, i2 As Long


Dim strText1 As String

strText1 = strText

Dim strText2 As String                                                      
i1 = 0                            
i2 = InStr(1, strText1, "")                           
strText2 = Mid(strText1, i1 + 1, i2 - i1 - 1)
Dim evaluate As Integer

Dim evaluate As Integer
evaluate = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sht.Range("A1:A" & 
lastRow), strText2)
```

Regards, Bruno

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are looking for a text that is only a part of what the cell contains (I am referring to `strText2 = Mid(...)`).
In that case, `CountIf` is not the correct solution in VBA, nor would it be in an Excel formula. [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) should be what you are looking for, possibly with [FindNext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext)

Try the piece of code below:

```
Dim rangeSearch as range
set rangeSearch = Sht.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Find(What:=strText2, Lookin:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not rangeSearch Is Nothing then
...
End if
```

Comment: I applied it but as I said, seems that the strText2 is not the same type as content typed in excel (range in A1:A& lastRow), its not matching the values even if  make sure that the range has the value presented in striText2

Comment: what if you just replace `strText2` with `"a"` or `"e"` or whatever single letter there is in the text?

Comment: I solved guys, the function is running. Seems that outlook was exporting a space character that I didn't see before.